# Find arrays that share a common value from collection of arrays. May be 0 or more matches

Tags: php, arrays, reduce, array-intersect

I have the following data structure:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'apple' (length=5)
      1 => string 'colophon' (length=8)
      2 => string 'byo-fusion-drive' (length=16)
      3 => string 'scroll-targeting' (length=16)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'apply' (length=5)
      1 => string 'exploring-web-typography' (length=24)
      2 => string 'on-performance-content-management' (length=33)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'macbook' (length=7)
      1 => string 'colophon' (length=8)
      2 => string 'nifty-minidrive' (length=15)
```

I'm trying to find out which, if any, arrays in my collection of arrays share a common value.

E.g: Arrays 0 and 2 share the string "colophon".

I've tried using array_intersect but this, of course, returns NULL since array 1 has no values in common with the others.

Also, it's possible (likely even) that in any given collection there will be no common value. The collection of arrays will always contain at least two arrays. There could be any number of additional arrays in the collection.

With the data described above, the end result should be something like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'apple' (length=5)
      1 => string 'colophon' (length=8)
      2 => string 'byo-fusion-drive' (length=16)
      3 => string 'scroll-targeting' (length=16)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'macbook' (length=7)
      1 => string 'colophon' (length=8)
      2 => string 'nifty-minidrive' (length=15)
```

I.e: With array 1 (from the original) being removed as it shares no common value.

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I have been trying for 8+ hours now and have decided to ask for help.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to iterate it with a nested loop. like so:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "apple",
        "colophon",
        "byo-fusion-drive",
        "scroll-targeting"
    ),
    array(
        "apply",
        "exploring-web-typography",
        "on-performance-content-management"
    ),
    array(
        "macbook",
        "colophon",
        "nifty-minidrive"
    )
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
        var_dump(array_intersect($array[$i], $array[$j]));
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
array (size=1)
  1 => string 'colophon' (length=8)
array (size=0)
  empty
```

---

A simple modification to the loop gives the expected behavior:

```
$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { //Start from the first array, and continue up to all of them.
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($array); $j++) { //Start with the current array of $i, +1. So that collisions never occur.
        if (count(array_intersect($array[$i], $array[$j])) !== 0) { //If there are common values (the array_intersect() function returns a non-empty array
            if (!in_array($array[$i], $result)) $result[] = $array[$i]; //Add the first array (if it's not there already)
            if (!in_array($array[$j], $result)) $result[] = $array[$j]; //Add the second array (if it's not there already)
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'apple' (length=5)
      1 => string 'colophon' (length=8)
      2 => string 'byo-fusion-drive' (length=16)
      3 => string 'scroll-targeting' (length=16)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'macbook' (length=7)
      1 => string 'colophon' (length=8)
      2 => string 'nifty-minidrive' (length=15)
```

Comment: Your solution works, in that it finds the one common value in the collection. I'm sure I could use this to produce the result I want. However, I haven't marked as "accepted solution" (yet) as the end result isn't quite what I'm looking for. Thank you for posting a valid solution though.

Comment: @DarkBlue: If a question proves useful to you, but not exactly "Correct", you can upvote it (clicking on the Triangle-up symbol above the question's score), without accepting it. (That's actually its purpose). Cheers.

Comment: You revised solution works perfectly. Thank you very much. Now to try and understand how it's working... :-)

Comment: @DarkBlue: Added comments to explain :)

Comment: You are an absolute star. I can't thank you enough. I was banging my head against the wall with this for more than 8 hours. I just couldn't figure it out. Your solution is elegant and concise and, now that I've read the comments, remarkably simple. I was attacking the problem from entirely the wrong direction. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$arr = array (
  array('apple', 'colophon', 'byo-fusion-drive', 'scroll-targeting', ),
  array('apply', 'exploring-web-typography', 'on-performance-content-management', ),
  array('macbook', 'colophon', 'nifty-minidrive', 'nifty-minidrive', ),
);

$repeated_values = array_keys(
  array_filter(
    array_count_values(
      array_reduce($arr, function ($res, $value) {
          return array_merge($res, array_unique($value));
        }, array()
      )
    ), function ($count) {
      return $count > 1;
  })
);

$result = array_filter($arr, function($value) use ($repeated_values) {
   if (sizeof(array_intersect($repeated_values, $value)) > 0) return true;
});

var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'apple' (length=5)
      1 => string 'colophon' (length=8)
      2 => string 'byo-fusion-drive' (length=16)
      3 => string 'scroll-targeting' (length=16)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'macbook' (length=7)
      1 => string 'colophon' (length=8)
      2 => string 'nifty-minidrive' (length=15)
      3 => string 'nifty-minidrive' (length=15)
```

Comment: The only reason I downvoted was because I saw the word "global" in your code.

Comment: @air4x This is generating a warning, "array_reduce() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in test.php on line 13". $result is NULL. Trying to debug.

Comment: @DarkBlue what is your php version ?

Comment: @air4x My PHP version is 5.3.2

Comment: @DarkBlue I don't have access to php 5.3.2, but I could find it working on php 5.3.3 and not working on php 5.2.17. Probably something used in array_reduce is not supported in php 5.3.2.

Comment: @air4x I am grateful for your efforts and for putting your time into this. I have 5.3.2 running locally and 5.3.14 on the web-host. **It doesn't work under 5.3.2 but works perfectly under 5.3.14.**

Comment: `if (sizeof(array_intersect($repeated_values, $value)) > 0) return true;` should be `return array_intersect($repeated_values, $value);`